# Winform: allow user to change colors of the app dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new in the big programming community, and got a small issue with my app.
I'd like the users to be able to click on a button and set the colors of the ENTIRE APP, like a theme. Here is how it looks right now, and some snippets of code I tried:

[https://imgur.com/eKAga22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oIfD.png)

As you can see, the button on the left using color1 (in Form1.cs), and even the button in the childform (Form_Settings.cs) don't change color at all.

**Form_Settings.cs**

```
private void trackBarR_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonRGB1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(trackBarR1.Value, trackBarG1.Value, trackBarB1.Value);
}
// my click event not working
private void buttonRGB1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ColorThemePicker.RGBColors.color1 = buttonRGB1.BackColor; // change variable from struct to the color set but doesn't work
    ActiveForm.Update(); // I tried to update the form but this doesn't seem to work
}
```

**ColorThemePicker.cs**

```
public struct RGBColors
{
    // RGBColors.color1
    public static Color color1 = Color.FromArgb(173, 112, 133); // (Color 1) Very dark pink
}
```

Am I missing something, or doing something wrong? All reference of the color I want to change are set as color1, example here of the button in the childform (Form_Settings.cs):

**Form_Settings.Designer.cs**

```
this.color1.BackColor = RGBColors.color1; // here you can see it's set as the color1 from the struct and not the usual system colors
this.color1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
this.color1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
this.color1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(407, 297);
this.color1.Name = "btn_color1";
this.color1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 67);
this.color1.TabIndex = 12;
this.color1.Text = "I\'m Color1";
this.color1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
```

Thank you for your help, I'd be happy with any kind of clue on how to progress, or even what to google.

Comment: `Color` is a `struct`, so `this.color1.BackColor = RGBColors.color1;` is the value of `RGBColors.color1` **at a point in time**. If you then change `RGBColors.color1` it won't propagate to `this.color1.BackColor`.

Comment: Do you re-apply `RGBColors.color1` to `color1.BackColor` anywhere except in the `Designer` file? The Designer code runs just once during initialization, it doesn't establish a "reactive" relationship. You need to write explicit code to re-set `color1.BackColor` when you want to change the color.

Comment: Use databinding to settings. It will give you design-time support as well as configurable settings support. Also use use ToolStripProfessional renderer with custom color table for ToolStrip, MenuStrip and ContextMenuStrip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow explanation:

```
// 1. Initialize the color1 to a value
public static Color color1 = Color.FromArgb(173, 112, 133); // (Color 1) Very dark pink
// 2. Take the color from RGBColors and assign very dark pink value to color1
this.color1.BackColor = RGBColors.color1; // here you can see it's set as the color1 from the struct and not the usual system colors
 // 3. Change the RGBColors.color1 from very dark pink to some other value           
ColorThemePicker.RGBColors.color1 = buttonRGB1.BackColor; // change variable from struct to the color set but doesn't work
// 4. Why would this assignment change the other variables value? (step 2)
```

Now imagine these were numbers instead of colors

1. Assign number 1 to var1
2. Assign var1 value to var2. Now var2 value is 1
3. Assign number 2 to var2. Did var1 value change? No it's still 1.

Structs are value types in c# as integers so the same rules apply.

As mentioned you should change the specific control's value to make this work

Comment: If I understand well, I need to set (for example) the button's Back color in Form_Setting.cs as RGBColors.color1 to make the value change? I'm kinda lost as what "specific control" means here, sorry!

Comment: You need to reassign `this.color1.BackColor = RGBColors.color1;`